# How to start Dartium / Chrome in checked mode for Dart in Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, dart, dartium

According to the docs:

https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dartium.html

In Mac and Linux you can append a `--checked` but this does not work for Windows.

How do I launch Dartium with the checked flag in Windows?

Comment: Update: The only way I have managed to launch Dartium in Windows with checked mode, is it I have launched it through Dart Editor. But, since I dont use dart editor, I want to launch it outside.

Comment: I do not imagine myself how to use Dart VM in "unchecked" mode. For me this is the same as you got behind the wheel of the car, close your eyes with both hands and push with all his strength on the gas pedal. Also works the Dart VM in "unchecked" mode - no brakes, no rules, only speed, speed and bang! The "unchecked" riding in an unknown direction.

Comment: As of may 2018, Dartium is deprecated. You should start migrating your code to Dart 2.0 according to this page: https://www.dartlang.org/dart-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, using `DART_FLAGS` works as well for Windows.

see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dartium/#using-command-line-flags

Command flags are prefixed with `/` on Windows, so you use:

```
C:\path\to\dartium\chrome.exe /DART_FLAGS='--checked'
```

Comment: How do you actually use this on Windows?

Comment: Apparently Stack Overflow rejected the undo of my edit.  `/DART_FLAGS='--checked'` does NOT work, it's disinformation, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `DART_FLAGS` environment variable:

Cmd.exe:

```
$> set DART_FLAGS=--checked
$> C:\path\to\dartium\chrome.exe
```

PowerShell:

```
$> $env:DART_FLAGS="--checked"
$> C:\path\to\dartium\chrome.exe
```