# Using CoreScaffold and CoreTabs classes now causes Exception

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a polymer element called main-app:

```dart
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_tabs.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_dialog.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_icon_button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_scaffold.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_header_panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_menu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_item.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_dialog.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_scaffold.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_pages.html">

    <polymer-element name="main-app" class="dark-primary-color">
        <template>
            <style type="text/css">
                :host {
                    display: block;
                }
            </style>
            <core-scaffold>

                <core-header-panel id="menu-panel" navigation flex>

                    <core-toolbar id="navheader">
                        <span>Menu</span>
                    </core-toolbar>
                    <core-menu>
                        <core-item label="Home" on-click="{{homeClicked}}"></core-item>
                        <core-item label="About Us" on-click="{{aboutClicked}}"></core-item>
                        <core-item label="Contact Us" on-click="{{contactClicked}}"></core-item>
                    </core-menu>
                </core-header-panel>

                <span tool>{{title}}</span>
                <paper-tabs class="main-menu bottom fit" selected="0">
                    <paper-tab on-click="{{homeClicked}}">Home</paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab on-click="{{aboutClicked}}">About Us</paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab on-click="{{contactClicked}}">Contact Us</paper-tab>
                </paper-tabs>
                <div class="content" forceNarrow>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
                </div>

                ...
            </core-scaffold>
        </template>
        <script type="application/dart" src="main-app.dart"></script>
    </polymer-element>
```

main-app.dart:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'util/util.dart';
import 'event/event.dart';

import 'dart:html';

import 'page/home-page.dart';
import 'page/about-page.dart';
import 'page/contact-page.dart';

@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  @observable String page = "home";
  @observable String title = "Home";

  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  ...

  homeClicked(event, detail, target) {
    CoreScaffold e = shadowRoot.querySelector('core-scaffold');
    e.doSomething <<-- fails
    ...
  }

  ...

}
```

This is the exception I'm getting:

```dart
Exception: 'package:falm/main-app.dart': malformed type: line 73 pos 5: type 'CoreScaffold' is not loaded
    CoreScaffold e = shadowRoot.querySelector('core-scaffold');
    ^
type 'CoreScaffold' is not a subtype of type 'malformed' of 'e'.
```

To get rid of the exception, I now have to do:

```dart
  homeClicked(event, detail, target) {
    Element e = shadowRoot.querySelector('core-scaffold');
    e.doSomething <<-- works
    ...
  }
```

The code that is failing was working until a dart update yesterday morning (not sure from which version I updated as I reinstalled the SDK completely before doing a full pub upgrade, pub cache repair and pub download), PaperTabs is doing the same thing.

Does this mean I can no longer use CoreElement and PaperTabs classes in my dart code?

Update: here are the relevant bits and pieces from pubspec.lock:

```dart
core_elements:
    description: core_elements
    source: hosted
    version: "0.6.0+4"
paper_elements:
    description: paper_elements
    source: hosted
    version: "0.6.0+4"
  polymer:
    description: polymer
    source: hosted
    version: "0.15.5"
  polymer_expressions:
    description: polymer_expressions
    source: hosted
    version: "0.13.0+1"
  web_components:
    description: web_components
    source: hosted
    version: "0.10.1"
```

Comment: You could have edited your previous question. Does your `main-app.dart` import `CoreScaffold`?

Comment: Didn't have to import it before, what dart file do I need to import to get the CoreScaffold class? Only seeing core-scaffold.html now.

Comment: `import 'package:core_elements/core_scaffold.dart';`

Comment: Maybe before the update your code was run in production mode and now is run in development mode (checked mode). Type annotations in Dart have no functionality and no meaning in production mode.

Comment: That's definitely a possibility, should I keep it in checked mode?

Comment: checked mode is for development. I think you should use it to spot errors early. Production mode ignores type annotation for improved speed.

Comment: I understand the packaging structure now, thanks Gunter! This fixed it for me: `import 'package:core_elements/core_scaffold.dart';`
`import 'package:paper_elements/paper_tabs.dart';`
and you were spot-on with the checked-mode. Where do I check if it's turned on or / off after I've imported a project? In intelliJ I see the option while importing the project, after that I don't know where to find it again.
I'll accept checked mode as well as the imports as correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the libraries where the class is defined.

```dart
import 'package:core_elements/core_scaffold.dart'; 
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_tabs.dart';
```

**checked/unchecked**

When you run a Dart script from **command line** the default is production mode (unchecked mode). `dart bin/somescript.dart`, or checked mode when set explicitely like `dart -c bin/somescript.dart`.

When you launch a Dart script or web app from **DartEditor** default is checked mode. DartEditor allows to (de)activate `Run in checked mode` in `Manage Launches` (run configurations).

I assume there is a similar setting in **Dart plugin for Eclipse** (don't use it myself).

**WebStorm** allows to set it for command line apps in `Run > Edit Configurations ...` . For web apps you can create a new browser config and add `--checked` in the `Command line options`.

I assume it's similar in **IntelliJ IDEA** but I haven't used it myself yet.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21658630/217408